# MySQL ORDER BY optimization in many to many tables

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `posts` (

  `post_n` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `id` int(10) default NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',

  PRIMARY KEY  (`post_n`,`visibility`),
  KEY `id` (`id`),
  KEY `date` (`date`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `subscriptions` (

  `subscription_n` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `subscribe_id` int(10) NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY  (`subscription_n`),
  KEY `id` (`id`),
  KEY `subscribe_id` (`subscribe_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

Query:

```
SELECT posts.* FROM posts, subscriptions 

WHERE posts.id=subscriptions.subscribe_id AND subscriptions.id=1 

ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 0, 15
```

It`s so slow because used indexes "id", "subscribe_id" but not index "date" thus ordering is very slow.

Is there any options to change the query, indexes, architecture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible Improvements:

First, you'll gain a couple microseconds per query if you name your fields instead of using SELECT posts.* which causes a schema lookup. Change your query to:

```
SELECT posts.post_n, posts.id, posts.date 
FROM posts, subscriptions 
WHERE posts.id=subscriptions.subscribe_id 
  AND subscriptions.id=1 
ORDER BY date DESC 
LIMIT 0, 15
```

Next, this requires MySQL 5.1 or higher, but you might want to consider partitioning your tables. You might consider KEY partitioning for both tables.

This should get you started.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-types.html

E.g.

```
SET SQL_MODE = 'ANSI';
-- to allow default date
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `posts` (
  `post_n` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `id` int(10) default NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`post_n`,`id`),
  KEY `id` (`id`),
  KEY `date` (`date`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin
PARTITION BY KEY(id) PARTITIONS 32;
--
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `subscriptions` (
  `subscription_n` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `subscribe_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`subscription_n`,`subscribe_id`),
  KEY `id` (`id`),
  KEY `subscribe_id` (`subscribe_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin
PARTITION BY KEY(subscribe_id) PARTITIONS 32;
```

I had to adjust your primary key a bit. So, beware, this may NOT work for you. Please test it and make sure. I hope, this does though. Make sure to run sysbench against the old and new structures/queries to compare results before going to production.
:-)

Comment: oh yeah, it`s something new for me. i will update mysql version and test it, thank you! :)

Comment: after adding partitioning speed increased in 2, it`s good. i need to test it more, thanx.

Comment: it always going throw all partitions, but if i order it in desc by date, than i need only last 15, always, maybe exists some another way for partitioning, do you know? sorry for my english.

Comment: You can RANGE partition by date. Read the docs and see if it makes sense for what you're trying.

Comment: have done queries ALTER TABLE posts PARTITION BY KEY(date) PARTITIONS 10; or ALTER TABLE posts PARTITION BY RANGE (year(date))(
PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (2010),
PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (2011)
) but if execute simple query: SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE year(date)=2009 it show that scanned all partiions not one. what did I go wrong?

Comment: What version of mysql are you running? SHOW @@version;

Comment: What partitioning buys you is not an automatic offset, rather a reduced file size. You still have to mix the write query structure with an index and partitioning to see the ultimate benefit. I will add to my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to modify the table, you could add a multi-field index containing both ID and date. (or modify one of the existing keys to contain them both).

If you can't make changes to the database, and if you know that your result set is going to be small, you can force it to use a specific named key, with `USE KEY(name)`. The ordering would then be done after the fact, just on the reslts returned.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I did as you said but no effect. Speed still 0.1

Comment: Without ordering 0.0013. I am in despair